# Associate Task with Changeset

Tags: tfs, checkin, changeset

In VS2015, how does one associate an existing task with a checked-in changeset? It should be possible, but I've only experienced several dead ends.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one path to success:

- Open the Task
- Click [Links] (between HISTORY and ATTACHMENTS)
- Click the icon below it with the specific Tool Tip "Link to ..."
- Click the Link Type drop-down and select Changeset
- Type in the Changeset or, if you're in an adventurous mood, use the browse button
- Fill in the comment
- Clicking [OK] should add the Changeset to the list of links
- Click [Save]